# How to change the default settings for ivy without modifying the ivy jar

Tags: settings, ivy

After using this website for about 3 years, this is the first question I couldn't resolve by any of the already posted questions on here.

As the title says, I am looking for a way to change some of ivys default settings for console and overall use without changing any of the files inside the ivy or ant jars.

to be exact I want to change the default public repository to our company repository.
Whilst I managed to do so for specific projects by adding the settings to the build.xml I could not find any (for me) understandable advise on how to change it per default as for example maven does with the settings.xml in .m2 folder.

TL;DR
 Can I have a settings file for ivy that is similar in behaviour to the settings file maven uses (.m2/settings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I have used one of the following approaches which I think are simpler and more practical, compared to the recommendations discussed in the [ivy documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/defaultconf.html).

### Project settings file

If ivy detects an ivysettings.xml file in the root directory of my project it will automatically used (no special configuration required)

```
├── build.xml
├── ivysettings.xml   <-- Custom settings here
├── ivy.xml
└── src
    └── files
```

### Host a central settings file

My standard resolve target references a common settings file located on a central server:

```
<target name="resolve" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
    <ivy:settings url="http://mysite.com/ivysettings.xml" />
    <ivy:resolve/>

    <ivy:report todir='${ivy.reports.dir}' graph='false' xml='false'/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly it is not what I am looking for, nevertheless it helped me. +1

Comment: Accepted because there are no better answers coming and because it's presumably not intended by ivy itself